# Create atmost one relationship for newly created node with existing node based on some property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My application receive stream of data which I need to persist in graph DB. With this data , I am first creating nodes in neo4j db in batches (of 1000) and just after that I am trying to find out matching node in existing data to link it.

```
MATCH(new:EVENT) where new.uniqueId in [NEWLY CREATED NODES UNIQUE ID]
MATCH (existing:EVENT)  where new.myprop = existing.myprop and new.uniqueId <> exising.uniqueID
CREATE (new)-[:LINKED]-(existing)
```

My problem is, if for a node there are more than one matching existing node than i want to create relationship with just one existing node. My current above  query will create relationship with all matching nodes.

is there any efficient way of doing it as number of existing node could be huge ie approx 300M.

Node: I have index created on myprop and uniqueId field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @InverseFalcon's answer states, you can use [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) to collect the `existing` nodes for each distinct `new`, and take the first in each collection.

For better performance, you should always [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) a query to see what can be improved. For example, after doing that with some sample data on my neo4j installation, I saw that: the index was not automatically being used when finding `new`, and the `new.uniqueId <> exising.uniqueId` test was causing DB hits. This query fixes both issues, and should have better performance:

```
MATCH(new:EVENT)
USING INDEX new:EVENT(uniqueId)
WHERE new.uniqueId in [NEWLY CREATED NODES UNIQUE ID]
MATCH (existing:EVENT)
WHERE new.myprop = existing.myprop AND new <> existing
WITH new, COLLECT(existing)[0] AS e
CREATE (new)-[:LINKED]->(e);
```

It uses `USING INDEX` to provide a hint to use the index. Also, since `uniqueId` is supposed to be unique, it just compares the `new` and `existing` nodes directly to see if they are the same node.

To ensure that the uniqueness is actually enforced by neo4j, you should create a [uniqueness constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#constraints-create-unique-constraint):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:EVENT) ASSERT e.uniqueId IS UNIQUE;
```

Comment: Thank  You, I will try this and observe performance on test data i have.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the existing node matches per new node and just grab the first:

```
MATCH(new:EVENT) where new.uniqueId in [NEWLY CREATED NODES UNIQUE ID]
MATCH (existing:EVENT)  where new.myprop = existing.myprop and new.uniqueId <> exising.uniqueID
WITH new, head(collect(existing)) as existing
CREATE (new)-[:LINKED]-(existing)
```